# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We are using an aura component which is call from a related list button and created in a vfPage using $Lightning.createComponent() method.
The component is used to send an email from his apex controller and then it redirects on the page where it was called.
But I'm receiving this error when I try to redirect to the account record page :

[image]

Here is my callback that triggers this error :

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log("In call back of notify component on send emails");
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){  
                console.log("In success");                                
                var event = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                event.setParams({
                    "url" : "/lightning/r/Account/"+component.get("v.recordId")+"/view",
                });
                console.log(event.getParam("url"));
                event.fire();
                
                var successMessage = $A.get("$Label.c.sfdc_sendForm_successMessage");
                var successToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                successToast.setParams({
                    "title" : "Success!",
                    "message" : successMessage,
                    "type" : "success"
                });
                successToast.fire();
```

I also tried with "e.force:navigateToSObject" event but got the same error.
Can you please help me ?

---

**UPDATE :**

I tried with the navigate function but it doesn't redirect me to the record page , juste a blank page, here the code with navigate :

```
            var action = component.get("c.sendEmailApex");
        action.setParams({
            "toAddress" : toEmails,
            "ccAddress" : ccEmails,
            "bccAddress" : bccEmails,
            "relatedTo" : relatedTo,
            "subject" : emailSubject,
            "body" : emailBody,
            "files" : fileIds
        });
        component.set("v.isMainModalOpen",false);
        component.set("v.showSpinner",true);
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log("In call back of notify component on send emails");
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){  
                console.log("In success");                                
                var navService = component.find("navService");
                // Sets the route to /lightning/r/Account/{acctid}/view
                var pageReference = {
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: component.get("v.recordId"),
                        objectApiName: "Account",
                        actionName: "view"
                    }
                };
                navService.navigate(pageReference);
                
                
            }else if(state === "ERROR"){                
                component.set("v.isMainModalOpen",true);
                console.log("In error");
                var errors = response.getError();
                if(response.getError()[0].message == 'SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: EMAIL_ADDRESS_BOUNCED, Email address marked as bounced: contact_r1@gmail.com: [toAddresses, contact_r1@gmail.com]')
                {
                    errors[0].message = 'Email of the account is invalid' 
                }
                console.log(errors);                
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title" : "Error!",
                    "message" : errors[0].message,
                    "type" : "error"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: have you tried by removing      console.log(event.getParam("url"));   and why you are not using navigateToSObject.  this case is more suitable for navigateToObject.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/specification

Comment: Can you paste the whole code and line where it is showing error? Because I didn't see anything wrong in this code. Error is due to some other part of code.